# The most secure login mode for web application

Tags: php, authentication

What options do i have to secure a webpage with a login. I need to make only the user to login to webpage.
I have read something about facial recognition.
Are there any ways to make the login secure and to allow only the user to being allowed to login.

Comment: Like a username and password over SSL?

Comment: You could even add 2 factor authentication.

Comment: No. I dont want user to share credentials.

Comment: So, your application needs higher security that worldwide banks? Good luck with that, sounds unlikely, but meh.

Comment: what about client certificate? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_certificate

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends entirely on how secure and what details are being stored. Since you have not clarified, I'll just say for simple name, password username some options.

The simplest way is to use a trusted authentication API to handle the login for you.

Google, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, GitHub and OpenID all handle this rather well. You're getting all the bulk of the work done for you with that and the majority of users trust it.

Some useful links:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html
https://developers.google.com/identity/